# Is xml-tag could use two namespaces or this is libxml2 bug?

Tags: c, xml, libxml2

I have the following *valid* XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <aaa xmlns:de="http://www.dolby.com/dcinema/ws/smi/v11/SPL" atr="abc" xmlns:fe="http://somewhere">
   some text
   <de:bbb atr1="abb" atr2="baa" >aaa</de:bbb>
   <de:ccc>aaa</de:ccc>
   <fe:ddd>bbb</fe:ddd>
   some more text
  </aaa>
```

And the following C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libxml/xmlreader.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>

char xml_data[] = {
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n"
    "  <aaa xmlns:de=\"http://www.dolby.com/dcinema/ws/smi/v11/SPL\" "
    "       atr=\"abc\""
    "       xmlns:fe=\"http://somewhere\">\n"
    "   some text\n"
    "   <de:bbb atr1=\"abb\"  atr2=\"baa\" >aaa</de:bbb>\n"
    "   <de:ccc>aaa</de:ccc>\n"
    "   <fe:ddd>bbb</fe:ddd>\n"
    "   some more text\n"
    "  </aaa>"
};

void printns(xmlNsPtr ns, int deep, char * marker)
{
    while (ns)
    {
        printf("%*c%s+%s\n", deep * 5 + 1, ' ', marker, ns->prefix);
        ns = ns->next;
    }
}

void printelem(xmlNodePtr ptr, int deep)
{
    printf("%*c%s\n", deep * 5, ' ', ptr->name);
    if (ptr->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) 
    {
        printns(ptr->nsDef, deep, "d");
        printns(ptr->ns,    deep, "u");
    }

    if (ptr->xmlChildrenNode) printelem(ptr->xmlChildrenNode, deep+1);

    if (ptr->next) printelem(ptr->next, deep);
}

int main(void)
{
    LIBXML_TEST_VERSION
    xmlInitParser();

    xmlDocPtr doc;
    doc = xmlReadDoc(BAD_CAST xml_data, NULL, NULL, XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS);

    printelem(doc->xmlChildrenNode, 1);

    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
 aaa
  d+de
  d+fe
      text
      bbb
       u+de
       u+fe
           text
      text
      ccc
       u+de
       u+fe
           text
      text
      ddd
       u+fe
           text
      text
```

As you see, libxml2 says that bbb and ccc have TWO namespaces at once, when ddd have one namespace, as expected. Is this some xml-standart rule which is unknown for me or is this libxml2 bug?

Comment: I don't think the XML is valid. It's well-formed.

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE] with code, please? And an exact version number that you're using.

Comment: The provided xml is absolutely valid, by standart and by any validators like http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ .

Will try to provide MCV ASAP.

Comment: It does not have a DTD or Schema, so it cannot be valid by definition. W3 validator says it's wellformed.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that a node "has a namespace"? Please explain which *libxml2* API you're using instead of coming up with a custom description of the parse tree.

Comment: Here is my MCV: http://pastebin.com/S7tCMAVM
here is the output of MCV: http://pastebin.com/KUqqjyFu (compile with `gcc test.c -o test.elf -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 && ./test.elf`)
The same thing as I descripted before - two namespaces for first two elements and one for third.
By "has a namespace" I mean that tag belongs to some namespace, like `de:aaa` - tag `aaa` belongs to namespace `de`

Comment: I added the code directly to your question. There's no reason to post code that is essential to answer your question on another site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of an XML element can obviously only have a single namespace. So you shouldn't think of the `ns` member in `struct _xmlNode` as a linked list. It actually points to an `nsDef` entry of an ancestor element. Use the `next` pointer only to iterate `nsDef`. If you change the `printf` statement in `printns` to also show the address of the `xmlNs` struct

```
printf("%*c%s+%s [%p]\n", deep * 5 + 1, ' ', marker, ns->prefix,
       (void*)ns);
```

the output becomes

```
 aaa
  d+de [0x9e9aff0]
  d+fe [0x9e9b1a0]
      text
      bbb
       u+de [0x9e9aff0]  // same as first entry in nsDef of aaa
       u+fe [0x9e9b1a0]  // should be ignored
           text
      text
      ccc
       u+de [0x9e9aff0]  // same as first entry in nsDef of aaa
       u+fe [0x9e9b1a0]  // should be ignored
           text
      text
      ddd
       u+fe [0x9e9b1a0]  // same as second entry in nsDef of aaa
           text
      text
```

Note that `ns` always points to the correct `xmlNs` of the element.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected that I only need to get the very first one, but needed someone to confirm it.